# Solving a PDE solved by the method of lines giving a warning about bad local spatial error estimate

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I use the method of lines to solve the PDE

```
 D[a[t, r], t, t] + 3/2 1/t*D[a[t, r], t] - 
  10/t*D[a[t, r], r, r] - 
  10/t*2/r D[a[t, r], r] + (t/10)^4*Sin[a[t, r]] == 0,
```

with the initial conditions

```
a[10, r] == 
 4 (ArcTan[Exp[(r - R0)]] + ArcTan[Exp[(-r - R0)]]),
Derivative[1, 0][a][10, r] == 0, 
Derivative[0, 1][a][t, ri] == 0,
```

The domain is

```
{r,ri,3R0+ri}, {t,10,32}
```

where *R0=10*. The theoretical value of *ri* is *0*, but to avoid the singularity *1/ri* in the PDE, I choose ri as a very small number e.g. *ri=10^(-4)*.

The solution is like "a wall", moving from *r=R0* to *r=ri=10^(-4)* with *t* increasing, and the wall becomes steeper and rippled.

The method I use to solve the PDE is the method of lines

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "Coordinates" -> 
{mygrid}}}
```

I define “mygrid” so I can have more points in the discretization of the spatial dimension (*r*). I try to distribute more points  in the steep part. For example:

```
Rmiddle6m = 0.1; Rmiddle5m = 0.2; Rmiddle4m = 0.5; Rmiddle3m = 1; 
Rmiddle2m = 2; Rmiddle1m = 3; Rmiddle0 = 4; Rmiddle1 = 5; Rmiddle2 = 6; 
Rmiddle3 = 8; 

mygrid = Rationalize[ Join[ri + Range[0, 
Rmiddle6m*1500]/1500, ri + Rmiddle6m + Range[1, (Rmiddle5m - 
Rmiddle6m)*1500]/1500, ri + Rmiddle5m + Range[1, (Rmiddle4m - 
Rmiddle5m)*1200]/1200, ri + Rmiddle4m + Range[1, (Rmiddle3m - 
Rmiddle4m)*1000]/1000, ri + Rmiddle3m + Range[1, (Rmiddle2m - 
Rmiddle3m)*600]/600, ri + Rmiddle2m + Range[1, (Rmiddle1m - 
Rmiddle2m)*300]/300, ri + Rmiddle1m + Range[1, (Rmiddle0 - 
Rmiddle1m)*80]/80, ri + Rmiddle0 + Range[1, (Rmiddle1 - 
Rmiddle0)*50]/50, ri + Rmiddle1 + Range[1, (Rmiddle2 - 
Rmiddle1)*30]/30, ri + Rmiddle2 + Range[1, (Rmiddle3 - 
Rmiddle2)*20]/20, ri + Rmiddle3 + Range[1, (3 R0 - Rmiddle3)*10]/10]]
```

It works as long as the solution is not so steep. But with *t* increasing (the wall becomes steeper), there will be a warning message: 
***scaled local spatial error estimate of ... at t = ... in the direction of independent variable r is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance.***

I think the warning message means that I did not solve the PDE accurately. Any ideas to avoid the problem? Or is there any method other than *methodoflines* to solve this PDE? Many thanks!

Comment: You'd better illustrate the problem with a single **working** example. Explanation is good, but explanation that breaks the code sample is not. Then, I know you're refering to the example solving Burgers' equation in the document of method of lines, but sadly `NDSolve` can't handle this type of problem well, at least now, AFAIK. The discontinuity generating from a smooth i.c. is just troublesome.